# MutableState in view model?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In all the examples I have seen with view models in combination with Jetpack Compose, one usually stores a state in the view model as MutableStateFlow and then applies collectAsState in the compose function in order to get a Compose state.

My question: Why not store the state directly in the view model, and not some flow? E.g.

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val showDialog = mutableStateOf(false)
}

@Compose
fun MyScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    Button(onClick = { viewModel.showDialog = true })
    if (viewModel.showDialog) {
        AlertDialog(...)
    }
}
```

The above code seems to run as intended. Is this a valid solution then?

Comment: You can do it anyway you like, its just matter of best practises. Check [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: Instead of doing that , i did this in order to encapulate my property and delagate savedStateHandle.Saveable to manage restoring state after process death

 private var _showDialog  by savedStateHandle.saveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val showDialog 
        get() = _showDialog

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes it certainly is. I don't know where you saw those examples, but this is indeed the recommended practice. You can check the `State` Codelab; it demonstrates how to replace the `LiveData` objects to `mutableStateOf` inside the `viewmodel`. Also, as far as the usage of `LiveData` and `Flow` is concerned, it is mainly for interoperability, as far as I know. The apps which are not fully built in Compose, but are being transferred, or apps which plan to use the view system alongside Compose. `mutableStateOf` is only for Jetpack compose and hence, developers will want to use `LiveData` in such cases. However, if you are building a brand new project, and want it to be composed of only Compose, then definitely go for what you've mentioned in the question. It is the correct way.

Comment: Great, thanks! Upon your suggestion I managed to find it in the Codelab. However, in the documentation (e.g. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state) there does not seem to be any mention of this.

Comment: I think the particular doc is outdated. The codelab is more recent (and as a matter of that fact, has also recieved updates recently), and is meant for developers to learn the concept, with best practices.

Comment: I have seen people face problems with recompositions using liveData while a simple swap with mutable State fixes the issue. It is built specifically for compose and I think is definitely the recommended way of doing it. Also, I don't know about that doc, but everywhere else that I have seen (in other docs), mutableStateOf IS the best implementation for Compose. The codelab is also by the author of those very docs, I think.

Comment: In theory the ViewModel should not know about implementation details of the UI or depend on classes which are given in the package _androidx.compose_. Otherwise you have to modify the ViewModel whenever you change the UI framework. But maybe I am too picky.

Comment: I'd like to disagree here, since Compose is a *declarative* framework, the correct way to store and read the data is indeed a centralised repository like a viewmodel. It has the advantages of being designed to survive the lifecycle of the app, while also acting as a single source of truth, making it an idea home of the reactive `MutableState<T>` objects Compose leverages.

Comment: How much should ViewModels be aware of Compose? One argument seems like it should be ignorant of Compose, and just communicate with the ui via states and events. Is it a reasonable goal that ViewModel would work equally well with an XML ui and a Compose ui?  (mutableStateOf is part of the compose.runtime library)

Comment: Ok, the former half of the question isn't very clear to me, but the latter half seems to ask whether it is reasonable to want your viewModel to be integratable with XML as well as Compose. Well, that's not exactly a question is it; your project should ideally be fully Compose-built, since XML is now almost completely outdated. However, if you're migrating, or there are elements that are not yet officially supported that leave you with no choice but to use XML, then obviously you'd want your XML to be compatible with your viewModel. I haven't exactly worked with XML-ViewModel combo, so wont say

Answer (score 11):

Using `mutableStateOf()` in a view model will work, but **this is no longer the best** approach.

If you look at the **latest version** of the official documentation, including the Now in Android reference app, view models should stay data-centric and therefore use the data-centric `MutableStateFlow` instead of the Compose-centric `mutableStateOf()`.

[Android Developer Guide – Foundation: Screen UI state](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting#screen-ui)

[Android Developer Guide – App Architecture: Mutating the UI state from background threads](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/state-production#mutating_the_ui_state_from_background_threads)

[Now in Android – View Model](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/feature/author/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/feature/author/AuthorViewModel.kt)

[Now in Android - Screen](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/feature/author/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/feature/author/AuthorScreen.kt)

Using `MutableStateFlow` also makes much more sense from a **unit test perspective**. When testing a view model in isolation, any dependency on Compose (or other UI-centric packages and classes) should be a red flag. In other words, why would you need any Compose dependencies when testing a view model?

Comment: 2 of your links return 404. Can you quote exact place from the links about why it is bad to use state in ViewModel? mutableStateOf() does work in tests so why is it a red flag?

Comment: From what I can tell, those links use `MutableStateFlow` but do not indicate whether or not it is better or worse than `mutableStateOf()`. I think the choice comes down to "it depends". I personally don't think it is worth worrying about it being "Compose-centric" since it is being used with Compose.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is better to use `MutableStateFlow` rather than `mutableStateOf` of Compose in ViewModel.

1. ViewModel should be independent of UI. It is not a good choice to use Compose in VM.
2. `MutableStateFlow` is multi-thread safe. You can use `MutableStateFlow.update{}` to update it in any thread or any coroutine context. However, `mutableStateOf` is not. You should use `Snapshot.withMutableSnapshot{}` to guarantee atomic updates in a multi-thread environment. See [official document](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/state-production#mutating_the_ui_state_from_background_threads).
   PS: `viewModelScope` is hardcoded to `Dispatcher.Main`, so in most case it's OK to use `mutableStateOf`.
3. It's hard to be activity-level lifecycle aware if you use `mutableStateOf` directly in `ViewModel`. There is no direct way to notify the upstream data source to stop updating when the application is switched to the background. For `Flow` Compose provides a extend function `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`, see the [blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/consuming-flows-safely-in-jetpack-compose-cde014d0d5a3) for details.

**Of course, if this is a simple program, I think it is acceptable to use Compose state directly in ViewModel** ([Some official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer#expose-ui-state) does the same).

Answer (score -1):

*Flow* comes from `kotlinx.coroutines` it's used to observe async changes, while *State* is for updating compose UI changes. You're to use Flow **regardless of UI** if you're following *subscribe to stream for changes* pattern. Again, you *can* follow some complicated/incomplete pattern, but why would you?