# Jetpack Compose doesn't recompose

Tags: android

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var isElementVisible by mutableStateOf(true)
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
}

@Composable
fun MyElement(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {
    if(!mainViewModel.isElementVisible){
        // This function is re-triggered correctly.
        // isElementVisible is correctly set to false.
        // Adding Box(){} here makes it always work.
        // So, it very much looks like an internal Compose v1.5.4 bug.

        return
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onPress = {
                        mainViewModel.isElementVisible = false

                        return@detectTapGestures
                    }
                )
            }
    )
}
```

Recomposition is never triggered (i.e. the element doesn't disappear immediately, it takes 30-60 seconds) when I update `isElementVisible` inside `onPress`, why is that?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. you should use```MutableStateFlow``` in ```ViewModel``` and then use ```observeAsState``` in ```Activity```.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `MutableStateFlow` which will trigger when the value changes and you can observe its value in `Activity` using `collectAsState`.

I have made a function in `ViewModel` which will change the `Visibility`.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _isElementVisible = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isElementVisible = _isElementVisible.asStateFlow()

    fun setVisibility(){
        _isElementVisible.value = false
    }

}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
}

@Composable
fun MyElement(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {

    val state = mainViewModel.isElementVisible.collectAsState()

    if(state.value) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Red)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(
                        onPress = {
                            mainViewModel.setVisibility()
                            return@detectTapGestures
                        }
                    )
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no requirement to use `MutableStateFlow` instead of `mutableStateOf`, and also the Composable function is triggered again, but recomposition doesn't happen in Compose internals (not in my code). It looks very much like a bug. I tested your code but it also doesn't work. An empty `Box` must be present in the scope of the function for it to work. Your function returns nothing in some circumstances and this doesn't actually trigger recomposition.

Comment: You may be doing wrong. I have tested code and it's working in my pc. and mutableStateFlow and mutableStsteOf both having different use

Comment: What you are doing wrong is using mutableStateOf in Viewmodel Rather it should used in Composable function

Comment: Thanks, but you said multiple times "this is wrong" but you never provided any explanation why. According to answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702217/mutablestate-in-view-model it is completely valid to use `mutableStateOf` in `ViewModel`, and this now fully works for me after adding `Box(){}` before `return`. It still looks like internal Compose v1.5.4 bug.

Comment: @Jimsea, have you tried to use your solution but invert if statement to remove return keyword at all?

Comment: @plplmax Yes, removing `return` keyword still makes it NOT work. Only including additional empty `Box(){}` makes it always work. So, the problem is most likely not with the `return` statement itself, but with lack of any compose element in the scope of the function. It fully works for me currently after adding empty `Box(){}` at all times (although I don't understand why), so this question is kind of solved.

Comment: @Jimsea, there is no 1.5.4 Compose compiler, maximum version is 1.5.3. What is your `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` in app `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Jimsea, I have tested your code and do not have any issues with kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.5.3 and UI libraries 1.5.4. Maybe you use experimental Kotlin 2.0 or have corrupted Gradle cache or something?

Comment: @plplmax v1.5.4 of libraries is available for me. I use `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.3"`. The error is definitely happening and I reproduced it like 100 times by this point on emulator and S21 device. Adding an empty `Box(){}` is the only successful fix I found. In the `onCreate` I insert Compose to XML's `FrameLayout`: `composeView.setContent { App(mainViewModel) }`. And in the `App` I use `MyElement` directly: `fun App(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) { MyElement(mainViewModel) }`, so I don't have any special config that could be interfering.