Observe BroadcastReceiver in view model using flows
I know this type questions have already been asked here but none of them worked for me so I'll ask here.
I'm developing a VPN app using kotlin and jetpack compose. The core of our app uses this custom V2ray Java module . The functionality works fine except i'm trying to observe or listen to what the broadcast reciever is returning (like connection status, ping, traffic...). as you can see in this file all the process related to VPN service is happening here I have already seen all the stack overflow similar questions but none of them helped.
here is my attempt at observing diffrent connections states in jetpack compose:
Here is my view model:
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mainRepo: MainRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    var showDialog = mutableStateOf(false)
    var connectedStatus = mainRepo.connectedStatus.value
    private val _isConnected = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isConnected: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isConnected

    private val _isConnecting = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isConnecting: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isConnecting
    private var v2rayBroadCastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null

    fun init(activity: Activity) {
        // Initialize the broadcast receiver and register it
        v2rayBroadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                // Update the states based on the broadcast message
                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "connection mode ${V2rayConfigs.serviceMode}")
                    when (Objects.requireNonNull<Serializable?>(
                        intent.extras!!
                            .getSerializable(V2rayConstants.SERVICE_CONNECTION_STATE_BROADCAST_EXTRA)
                    ) as V2rayConstants.CONNECTION_STATES) {
                        V2rayConstants.CONNECTION_STATES.CONNECTED -> {
                            Log.e("TAG", "connected")
                            _isConnected.emit(true)
                            _isConnecting.emit(false)
                        }

                        V2rayConstants.CONNECTION_STATES.DISCONNECTED -> {
                            Log.e("TAG", "DISCONNECTED")
                            _isConnected.emit(false)
                            _isConnecting.emit(false)
                        }

                        V2rayConstants.CONNECTION_STATES.CONNECTING -> {
                            Log.e("TAG", "CONNECTING")
                            _isConnected.emit(false)
                            _isConnecting.emit(true)
                        }

                        else -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            activity.registerReceiver(
                v2rayBroadCastReceiver,
                IntentFilter(V2rayConstants.V2RAY_SERVICE_STATICS_BROADCAST_INTENT),
                AppCompatActivity.RECEIVER_EXPORTED,
            )
        } else {
            activity.registerReceiver(
                v2rayBroadCastReceiver,
                IntentFilter(V2rayConstants.V2RAY_SERVICE_STATICS_BROADCAST_INTENT),
            )
        }
    }

    fun startTestV2ray(
        remark: String,
        config: String,
        activity: Activity,
    ) {
        mainRepo.startTestV2ray(activity = activity, remark = remark, config = config)
    }

    fun stopTestV2ray(activity: Activity) {
        V2rayController.stopV2ray(activity)
    }
}

And here is where I call the init() funtion:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.init(this@MainActivity)

        V2rayController.init(
            this,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
            this.getString(R.string.app_name)
        )

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            SparrowTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    val navController = rememberNavController()

                   // other jetpack code such as Navgraph...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And as for the flows I simply call them in my composables as a simple val isConnected by mainViewModel.isConnected.collectAsState() but I always get false.
The weird thing is that the Log()s  in my viewmodels are working and it shows the diffrent states but the flows are not getting emmited.
One of the other solutions I tried is I copied all of the parts in the V2ray module that had anything to do with connection (such as this and this) in my main app module (and turned it into Kotlin) to try and connect it to view model's flows (because we don't have access to app module classes in other modules and besides the V2ray module is in Java) but i got this Receiver not registered exception error.


When you receive a broadcast, are you in MainActivity?


How use viewModel?  do you inject viewModel to your fragment?

i use this code private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels() to use viewmodel in main activity and i don't have a fragment it's jetpack compose

I do nut fully understand the code you posted but when Log.e("TAG", "connected") is executed then _isConnected.emit(true) is executed as well. From what I can see nothing should prevent the flows to work as expected. This leaves two options: Either there's something wrong in your composables that consume the flows or the flows' values are changed back immediately.
There are several issues in your code that makes it harder to understand what's going on, but as far as I can tell they shouldn't be causing the flows not to behave as expected. One thing you could try, though, is to replace your flows with a callbackFlow. That's the recommended way to convert callbacks (like onReceive) to flows. Here is an example for BroadcastReceiver. Your two flows will be reduced to one flow, so instead of having two booleans you should use a data structure like this for the new flow's value:
sealed interface ConnectionState {
    data object Connecting : ConnectionState
    data object Connected : ConnectionState
    data object Disconnected : ConnectionState
}

Use a private function in the view model (or maybe even the repository) that returns the callbackFlow and then pass it on to the UI like this:
val connectionState = connectionState().stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = ConnectionState.Disconnected,
)

private fun connectionState(): Flow<ConnectionState> {
    // return callbackFlow here
}

The context you need to call registerReceiver should be injected by Hilt. This works out of the box:
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mainRepo: MainRepository,
    @ApplicationContext private val appContext: Context,
) : ViewModel() {
    // you can now call appContext.registerReceiver(...)
}

Your Activity won't need to call some init function anymore and you should move the view model instantiation in your compose code so it isn't a property of your activity anymore:
val viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()


Most likely unrelated to your current problem, but these issues should be fixed as well:

Use collectAsStateWithLifecycle instead of collectAsState. Also see here: How to safely (lifecycle aware) .collectAsState() a StateFlow?

If your app only uses Compose and no Fragments then make your MainActivity extend ComponentActivity directly instead of AppCompatActivity. Also see here: ComponentActivity vs AppCompatActivity in Android Jetpack Compose

Move V2rayController.init to the repository/data source where you use V2rayController. The context you need should be injected by Hilt.

Also replace AppCompatActivity.RECEIVER_EXPORTED with Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED

viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) doesn't make sense. Your function is called from the UI so it already runs on the main thread. What you want instead is to move it away from that thread. You should use Dispatchers.IO here.

_isConnected (also applies to _isConnecting) is a MutableStateFlow, so instead of _isConnected.emit(true) you should use _isConnected.value = true. Also see here: MutableStateFlow difference between value and emit

Don't use MutableState (like showDialog) in your view model (or even repositories). Use a (private) MutableStateFlow with a dedicated setter function instead. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74601657

Make sure isConnected (also applies to isConnecting) cannot be casted back to MutableStateFlow:
val isConnected: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isConnected.asStateFlow()


Replace the verbose Java construct Objects.requireNonNull<Serializable?> with the much more concise requireNotNull from Kotlin.


