How to test SnapshotStateList being updated
I have
class MyViewModel(private val activitiesRepo: ActivitiesRepo) : ViewModel() {

    val activities = mutableStateListOf<Activity>()

    private var activitiesFlow =
        activitiesRepo.getAllActivitiesFlow().shareInViewModel(viewModelScope)

    fun initialize() {
        fetchActivities()
        collectActivities()
    }

    private fun fetchActivities() =
        viewModelScope.launch {
            activitiesRepo.fetchAllActivities()
        }

    private fun collectActivities() = viewModelScope.launch {
        activitiesFlow.collectLatest { newActivities ->
            this@MyViewModel.activities.clear()
            this@MyViewModel.activities.addAll(newActivities)
        }
    }
}

and I would like to test that activities state is updated with the data collected in collectActivities()
I tried many approaches, but activities are always an empty snapshot state list.
Here is one example of what I tried:
class MyViewModelTest {

    private val activitiesRepo: ActivitiesRepo = mockk(relaxed = true)
    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        viewModel = MyViewModel(activitiesRepo = activitiesRepo)
    }


    @Test
    fun `initialize updates activities list`() = runTest {
        val mockActivities = listOf(Activity(id = 1))
        every { activitiesRepo.getAllActivitiesFlow() } returns flowOf(mockActivities)
        
        // Launch the collection of activities in the ViewModel
        viewModel.initialize()

        advanceUntilIdle()

        assertThat(viewModel.activities).containsExactlyElementsIn(mockActivities)
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}


This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't even use MutableState in the view model in the first place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74601657
If you cannot or don't want to switch out your MutableState with a MutableStateFlow you need to wrap all write access to the MutableState with Snapshot.withMutableSnapshot so the Compose runtime is notified of the change, even when it was triggered from a non-composable context (like your test).

thanks, the only problem is, I work on a huge repository that never had any tests written. Let's not get into details why, I'm writing it more from the point of view - there's hundrets of mutable states, in tens of view models. At the time when the approach was introduced it was the recommended way (in official docs) and refactoring this approach for the sake of tests is simply not feasible at the moment. So I'm more looking for a way to manually trigger the update in test. I know it's not ideal, but it's this or no tests and I do want to introduce tests to my company.

It should probably be enough if you wrap viewModel.initialize() in your test in Snapshot.withMutableSnapshot, since that seems to be the only location where any changes to the MutableState are triggered. But this is 1.) not how your actual code calls the function, so you are technically testing something else and 2.) very brittle because minor changes to the internals of the view model may lead to failing tests.
