Android ViewModel with Room database query and Jetpack Compose
I am working on an app that has a typical list and detail view. When I enter data into the detail form and save, the list doesn't refresh to include the new item. Here's some code to show what I'm doing:
ListScreen:
@Composable
fun ListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    db: BaseballCardDatabase,
) {
    val viewModel: ListViewModel =
        viewModel(factory = ListViewModelFactory(db.baseballCardDao))
    val cards by viewModel.baseballCards.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = emptyList())
    val stateList by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            cards
                .map { card ->
                    SelectedState(
                        card,
                        false
                    )
                }
                .toMutableStateList()
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = { AddCardButton(navController) },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) { innerPadding ->
        BaseballCardList(
            navController = navController,
            cards = stateList,
            onCardChanged = { index, card -> stateList[index] = card },
        )

    }
}

ListViewModel:
class ListViewModel(val baseballCardDao: BaseballCardDao) : ViewModel() {
    val filterState = MutableStateFlow(FilterState())
    val isFiltered = mutableStateOf(false)
    val baseballCards = MutableStateFlow<List<BaseballCard>>(emptyList())

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            filterState.collect { filter ->
                baseballCards.value = getBaseballCards(
                    filter.brand,
                    filter.year,
                    filter.number,
                    filter.playerName,
                    filter.team
                ).first()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getBaseballCards(
        brand: String,
        year: Int,
        number: String,
        playerName: String,
        team: String,
    ): Flow<List<BaseballCard>> {
        return baseballCardDao.getBaseballCards(
            "%$brand%",
            year,
            "%$number%",
            "%$playerName%",
            "%$team%",
        )
    }

    fun applyFilter(filter: FilterState) {
        filterState.value = filter
        isFiltered.value = filter != FilterState()
    }
}


BaseballCardDao:
@Dao
interface BaseballCardDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertBaseballCard(card: BaseballCard)

    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM baseball_cards")
    val baseballCards: Flow<List<BaseballCard>>

    @Query(
        "SELECT * FROM baseball_cards " +
        "WHERE brand LIKE :brand " +
        "  AND (year = :year OR -1 = :year) " +
        "  AND number LIKE :number " +
        "  AND player_name LIKE :playerName " +
        "  AND team LIKE :team"
    )
    fun getBaseballCards(
        brand: String,
        year: Int,
        number: String,
        playerName: String,
        team: String,
    ): Flow<List<BaseballCard>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM baseball_cards WHERE _id = :id")
    suspend fun getBaseballCard(id: Long): BaseballCard
}


I recently added the filtering logic. Prior to that I just had val baseballCards = baseballCardDao.baseballCards and the list worked as I expected. It would recompose when there was any change to the database, I assume because the Flow provided a new list of cards for the UI to render. But now that I"m calling getBaseballCards() with the filter parameters, the list doesn't recompose like I want it to.
One solution I have tried is to just call getBaseballCards() each time I add a card, delete a card, or edit a card. But then this makes it so I don't really need a Flow and can just return a List directly. Is there a way to make this work with Flow?
For more context, the full project can be found here

Your call to first() basically eliminates the Flow, by saying that you only ever care about the first element emitted by the Flow. You may be able to get more of what you want if remove the init block and have val baseballCards = filterState.flatMapLatest { } to apply your filters. If this works how I expect (by eyeball...), you will wind up with new emissions if either the filter changes or the database changes.

@CommonsWare Thanks for the comment. The call to first() seems to be the proximate problem here. I'm rethinking some of the design decisions here. But I think your suggestions still apply. A friend suggested callbackFlow() in conjunction with flatMapLatest(), so I'm trying to figure out how those work.

You shouldn't collect flows in the view model (first is a special collect function that stops collection after the first value was received, hence the name). Instead you should only transform the flows and finally expose them as a StateFlow:
val baseballCards: StateFlow<List<BaseballCard>> = filterState
    .flatMapLatest(::getBaseballCards)
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5.seconds),
        initialValue = emptyList(),
    )

I changed getBaseballCards to this to make it easier to use:
private fun getBaseballCards(filter: FilterState): Flow<List<BaseballCard>> =
    baseballCardDao.getBaseballCards(
        "%${filter.brand}%",
        filter.year,
        "%${filter.number}%",
        "%${filter.playerName}%",
        "%${filter.team}%",
    )

Now you can remove the entire init block. Also you don't need the initialValue parameter of collectAsStateWithLifecycle anymore.

There are some other things that look fishy in your code. For example, you should never use MutableState in your view model. There are some nasty edge-cases where this doesn't behave as one might think. Simply replace it with MutableStateFlow. All MutableStateFlows in the view model should be private so they cannot be directly accessed from the outside. Expose a function for that like your applyFilter.
Also stateList looks like it won't work as intended. For example, it resets when the device is rotated. Also a new list from the database seems to overwrite everything with false. And what happens when the order of the cards is modified? Working with the index seems to be wrong. I think this should be moved to the view model:
private val _selectedCards = MutableStateFlow(emptySet<Int>())
val selectedCards = _selectedCards.asStateFlow()

fun selectCard(card: BaseballCard) {
    _selectedCards.update { it + card._id }
}

fun unSelectCard(card: BaseballCard) {
    _selectedCards.update { it - card._id }
}

In your composables just collect the selectedCards flow as usual and use its content to update the UI accordingly. If you don't want to have two different flows remove selectedCards and merge _selectedCards into baseballCards like this:
val baseballCards: StateFlow<List<SelectedState>> = combine(
    filterState.flatMapLatest(::getBaseballCards),
    _selectedCards,
) { cards, selected ->
    cards.map { card ->
        SelectedState(
            card,
            selected.contains(card._id),
        )
    }
}.stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5.seconds),
    initialValue = emptyList(),
)


Regarding your comment, you only need callbackFlow if a data source doesn't support flows out-of-the-box. It bridges callback-based APIs and the world of Flows. Since your DAO already returns a Flow there is no need for callbackFlow.

Thank you for the answer to my question and additional exceptions. I have a couple of comments and questions: 1) Can you elaborate on what are the drawbacks of calling collect() or variants in the ViewModel? Is this a technical thing or architectural? 2) My friend corrected his suggestion. He meant snapshotFlow rather than callbackFlow. I found an implementation that "works" using it. But it includes calling collect() in the init block of my ViewModel so I'm inclined to use your suggestion instead.


Thanks for pointing out the issues with stateList (which probably needs renamed). I'll look at this more.



If you collect flows in the view model you cannot control the flow chain anymore from the UI. With collectAsStateWithLifecycle you subscribe and unsubscribe from the flow as needed (like pausing the collection when the UI isn't visible, f.e. the app is sent to recents). The StateFlow can now also stop the upstream flow (after a 5 seconds delay), saving resources. That wouldn't be possible with your solution, collecting the flow in the init block.



See here for more details on why MutableState shouldn't be used in view models: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702217/mutablestate-in-view-model -- Without MutableState you also don't need snapshotFlow (it converts Compose State updates into a Flow, but you shouldn't have Compose State in the view model.).

